# Recreating a sentence from a list of indexed words

Tags: python

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to recreate the sentence:

**"Believe in the me, that believes in you!"**

(a little cringe for those who have watched Gurren Lagann...) while using the indexes that I obtained by enumerating the list of words:

***['believe', 'in', 'the', 'me', 'that', 'believes', 'you']***

This list was .split() and .lower() to remove punctuation in a previous bit of code I made to make the words list file and index list file.
When indexed, these are the words in their enumerated form:

***(1, 'believe')
(2, 'in')
(3, 'the')
(4, 'me')
(5, 'that')
(6, 'believes')
(7, 'you')***

That is all I have so far as I have been searching for a solution which none have worked for my code. Here is the whole thing so far:

```
with open("Words list file 2.txt", 'r') as File:
    contain = File.read()
    contain = contain.replace("[", "")
    contain = contain.replace("]", "")
    contain = contain.replace(",", "")
    contain = contain.replace("'", "")
    contain = contain.split()
print("The orginal file reads:")#prints to tell the user the orginal file
print(contain)

for i in enumerate(contain, start = 1):
    print(i)
```

Comment: why not `" ".join(['believe', 'in', 'the', 'me', 'that', 'believes', 'you'])` ? I see, you dumped your data as python list in a file. So now you have to parse back a python list... whats in your input file? and can you tell us the expected output?

Comment: Without the punctuation recorded it is impossible to recreate the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join the strings in list via using `join` method as:

```
my_list = ['believe', 'in', 'the', 'me', 'that', 'believes', 'you']
>>> ' '.join(my_list)
'believe in the me that believes you'
#                                ^ missing "in"
```

But this will result in string with missing `"in"` after `"believes"`. If you want the make a new string based on index of words in previous list, you may use a temporary list to store the index and then do `join` on a *generator expression* as:

```
>>> temp_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6]
>>> ' '.join(my_list[i] for i in temp_list)
'believe in the me that believes in you'
```

Comment: Good answer (+1). A more idiomatic possibility is to use a dictionary keyed by the words where the values are lists of indices corresponding to word occurrences, though that might be beyond OP's current knowledge of Python.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well! In the original sentence, I actually removed all repeats of words as that was the task I was given. Yes, I'm very new to Python so I appreciate the help you have given me and anyone here in understanding my mistakes and where I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join(['believe', 'in', 'the', 'me', 'that', 'believes', 'you'])
```

Not sure what the original file contains or what the "contains" variable is when loaded from the file. Please show that.